# ng-repeat not working with set data structure

Tags: angularjs, set, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` with a field that is a `Set` in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set. I tried use values(), keys(), entries() method from Set with ng-repat but is not working, anybody know a way, hack for this work?

Resumed code:

```
function Campaign () {
  this.site = {
    type : '',
    domains : new Set()
  };
}
```

controller:

```
.controller('CampaignStep1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'languages', 'geoLocationService',
        function ($scope, languages, geoLocationService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.campaign = $scope.campaign;
 }
```

html:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-empty-message" ng-repeat="domain in vm.campaign.site.domains">
  <td colspan="2">{{domain}}</td>
</tr>
```

Note: If i use console.log() and print domains attribute, it prints, i think that problem only is with ng-repeat.

Comment: `Set()` is a EMCAScript 6 feature.  Angular 1.x doesn't support ES6 features directly in this manner.  You could try using `ng-repeat = "domain in Array.from(vm.campaign.site.domains)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution but you can make it work like this:

View:

```
<p ng-repeat="value in getSetAsArr(set)">{{ value }}</p>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getSetAsArr = function (set) {
    var arr = [];
    set.forEach(function (value) {
        arr.push(value);
    });

    return arr;
};
```

Comment: I`m going to try this.

Comment: Not is the best solutions but works. Im going to try this method in the Set() method i think that is useful until angularjs support Set().

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 option -

```
return [...domains];
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution

```
var devSet = new Set();
devSet.add(""One);
devSet.add(""Two);
...
$scope.deviceTypes = Arrays.from(devSet);
```

And in html

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="type in deviceTypes">
      <p>{{type}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```